# Unable to send email variable in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am generating below data on a jquery oncliick event.

```
      $('<tr class="row-drop">'+
                '<td colspan="'+tr.children().length+'">'+
                     '<div class="float-right">'+
                       '<button type="submit" class="button glossy mid-margin-right with-tooltip" title="This feature is currently not available ">'+
                        '<span class="button-icon"><span class="icon-mail"></span></span>'+
                        'Send mail'+
                    '</button>'+
                    '<button type="submit" class="button glossy with-tooltip" onclick="callnow('+pname+'+,'+pemail+','+pnumber+','+pcode+','+pdelay+')"     title="This feature is currently disabled">'+                         '<span onclick="callnow(pname,pemail,pnumber,pcode,pdelay);" class="button-icon green-gradient"><span class="icon-phone"></span></span>'+
                        'Call Now'+
                    '</button>'+
                    '</div>'+
      '<div class="float-left">'+
  //              '<strong>Prospect Name:&nbsp;&nbsp;</strong><span style="color:white;">'+date+'</span><br>'+
                '<strong>Prospect Title:&nbsp;&nbsp;</strong>'+title+'<br>'+
                '<strong>Prospect Company:&nbsp;&nbsp;</strong>'+company+'<br>'+

                '<strong>Track id:&nbsp;&nbsp;</strong>'+ trackid +'<br>'+



            '</td>'+

        '</tr>').insertAfter(tr);
```

Which is appearing properly now there is line a in code

```
onclick="callnow('+pname+','+pemail+',+pnumber+,+pcode+,+pdelay+') >'
```

Where pname and pemail are the javacsript variable I am populating thoose from the same function I have generated previously

My problem is while clicking on `call now` button I am getting the javascript error which is

```
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
[Break On This Error]   

callnow(Naveen,nma@srdia.com.au,+pnumber+,+pcode+,+pdelay+);
```

Please help me out how to solve this issue .

I tried putting pemail in `encodeURI`   but still getting the same ,

Comment: Syntax highlighting is your friend... see that?

Comment: Forget it. I refuse to help. This is an awful question where the OP has taken recommendations from answers then replaced his code in the original question. Not only that, there is no update as to what could possibly be wrong. This is an awful question, with little value for anybody else stopping by. Flagged as too localized, and -1.

Answer (score 0):

Mistake.You need " character

```
onclick="callnow('+pname+','+pemail+',+pnumber+,+pcode+,+pdelay+')" >'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
onclick="callnow('+pname+','+pemail+',+pnumber+,+pcode+,+pdelay+') >'
```

Right after >> onclick << you start with " instead of ' like your used to to in the rest of the code. I would recommend you to bring this code to a better and more readable structure.
Enjoy your day!